# SEO Problems while using Pagination technique

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i created a video photo library / video library, there i have many rows where i places the icons against video or Image, & because of the length of the page i used the jquery pagination technique, Now i have 2 problems (1) SEO Problem, if anyone search any data that i have on the other than the 1st page, it shows in search engine & when user click on that link it land on the 1st page, not on the relevant page, (2) when user click on the next page, the view will stile on the pagination i want it goes on the top of the page or top of the table,

Link of that page "http://funswith.com/Multimedia/Video/Indian-Songs.html#pg=1"

any one can help me in this situation?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of [Making Ajax Applications Crawlable](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html) as written by google.

In brief: Instead of `www.example.com/ajax.html#key=value` use `www.example.com/ajax.html#!key=value` as your scheme.

Then respond appropriately to requests in this format: `www.example.com/ajax.html?_escaped_fragment_=key=value`

Comment: i changed my url from #key=value to #!key=value, but the problem is that, i don't know how to implement the 2nd phase that you tell me `www.example.com/ajax.html?_escaped_fragment_=key=value` because i'm new & don't have any experience with this, you can explain me in detail that how i can implement that.

Comment: The linked page is more detailed than I can be: http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/html-snapshot.html At the moment I assume some content gets returned from the server when you update your hash. You need to make it also accessible when that hash is passed to the server via the `_escaped_fragment_` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your scrolling issue, you'll want to add just one line of code to `pager.showPage()`.  To scroll to the top of the table, add this line:

```
document.getElementById(tableName).scrollIntoView();
```

Or, to scroll to the top of the page, add this line:

```
scrollTo(0, 0);
```

For the SEO work, follow [wombleton's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109590/seo-problems-while-using-pagination-technique/6110103#6110103).

Comment: where i have to put this line `scrollTo(0, 0);` 

in html page under this line `pager.showPage()`

or in paging.js file

Comment: In paging.js.  Add it right after the line `this.showRecords(from, to);`

Answer (score 0):

See that your url container fragement #pg=1 by default when you point to such link it will move your view there. As an workaround you can write window.scroll(0,0); on your page to always be on top. For your SEO problem it seems like a usability problem which has to be resolved using some design changes. Also doesnot your search results give the url as

http://funswith.com/Multimedia/Video/Indian-Songs.html#pg=4
http://funswith.com/Multimedia/Video/Indian-Songs.html#pg=3

i mean the page numbers.

Comment: So it's means SEO has no solution?